# Cause: couldn't make a guess for com.Application

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx

I migrated to Androidx using Android studio `Refator-> Migrate to Androidx`
It caused the app not to build and throwing error `Cause: couldn't make a guess for com.Application.MyClass`
MyClass uses `databinding` and the problem is surely related to `databinding`. I found in [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70921805) and also from search that problem might be package name because my package name has a capital letter in it. The problem here is I can not change the package name because it's already in play store with so many users. Any solution for this?

```
dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta02') {
            exclude module: 'proguard-gradle'
        }
        classpath('net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.2.1') {
            force = true
        }
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.6.201602180812'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}
```